W1023 signed/unsigned error on undefined compiler directive
Some 3rd party software that we use has this in an .inc file:
{$IF DEFINED(fpc) and (fpc_version < 3)}
if IsConstructor or IsVirtualCons then
  tbtu32(res.dta^) := RealCall_Register(Address, EDX, EAX, ECX, @Stack[Length(Stack) - 3], Length(Stack) div 4, 4, nil)
else
{$IFEND}

Obviously, this is for FreePascal support (32 bits in this case).
The Delphi 11.1 compiler gives a W1023 Comparing signed and unsigned type on the IF DEFINED line. fpc_version is undefined at this point, and frankly, I wonder about the validity of the and (fpc_version < 3) part.
Of course I can prevent the warning with
{$WARN COMPARING_SIGNED_UNSIGNED OFF}
{$IF DEFINED(fpc) and (fpc_version < 3)}
{$WARN COMPARING_SIGNED_UNSIGNED ON}

or by commenting out that portion because we don't use FreePascal, but I'm surprised that the warning pops up.
Why would the compiler give this warning on an undefined compiler 'variable'?
Is this something that is allowed in FreePascal but not in Delphi?

I can reproduce in 12.1 w/ Patch 1. I have filed a bug report: RSS-1074: W1023 warning when comparing an undefined identifier in an $IF directive

If you break up the $IF directive into 2 $IFs: {$IF DEFINED(fpc)}{$IF fpc_version < 3}...{$IFEND}{$IFEND} then the compile fails: E2026 Constant expression expected which clearly violates documented behavior, so I have filed a bug report for that, too: RSS-1075: E2026 error when evaluating an $IF directive with an undefined identifier
